# Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/chromium-browser

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, nestjs, puppeteer

I want to generate pdf from puppeteer package. I am using docker and nestjs as language. When I try to run the code, it says Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/chromium-browser ENOENT
My current OS is macos m1 chip

Now, I have tried many things
Used these and also changes headless property to false;

```
puppeteer.launch({
      dumpio: true,
      headless: true,
      executablePath: "/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
      args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu"],
    });
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.18.1 As development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev
RUN apt-get install -y \
    fonts-liberation \
    gconf-service \
    libappindicator1 \
    libasound2 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libcairo2 \
    libcups2 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libgbm-dev \
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libicu-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libpango-1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libpng-dev \
    libx11-6 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxext6 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxi6 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxss1 \
    libxtst6 \
    xdg-utils
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install
RUN npm i puppeteer
RUN chmod -R o+rwx node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
RUN npm install --only=development
COPY . .
RUN npm install rimraf
RUN npm run build
FROM node:14.2.0 as production
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

Here is my code

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        dumpio: true,
        headless: true,
        executablePath: "/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
        args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu"],
      });

      // create a new page(opening a new tab with new page)
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      // set html inside page
      await page.setContent(html);

      // provide some options(eg: width, height) to page
      const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf(options);

      // clear out our Puppeteer instance to free memory
      await page.close();
      await browser.close();
      console.log("PDF buffer is", pdfBuffer);
      return pdfBuffer;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error is", error);
    }
```

There many solutions for these, I tried most of the links, but none of them are working out. Its almost been 2hrs, but I am not able to reach solution for it.

Some of the things are tried out:

1. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker
2. https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/13461/how-to-run-puppeteer-and-headless-chrome-in-a-docker-container/